Is it possible to transfer an eSim from my Galaxy S20 to iPhone 15 Pro?
I have an old Galaxy S20 with an eSIM from T-Mobile for a secondary phone that I used to use. Some time ago I bought an iPhone 15 Pro and I have my main eSIM on it.
Is it possible to transfer the eSIM from the Galaxy S20 to my iPhone and have dual SIMs on the iPhone? If yes, then how do I do it?

Follow T-Mobile instructions to install the eSIM for your Galaxy S20 line onto to your iPhone.
The approximate steps will be:

Contact T-Mobile and provide the EID of the iPhone and associate it with the line you want to move.
You may receive a notification on your iPhone to install the eSIM. If you do not, follow whichever instructions T-Mobile provides to provision the eSIM.

